# mongodb "Continuing to delete old records to make room"

Tags: linux, mongodb

I see a lot of error messages in my mongodb primary server
like

```
    2016-07-14T15:15:13.657+0000 I STORAGE  [conn1264360] passes = 5000 in CappedRecordStoreV1::allocRecord: ns: local.oplog.rs, lenToAlloc: 3332496, maxCappedDocs: 9223372036854775807, nrecords: 
85038795, datasize: 52320193000. Continuing to delete old records to make room.
2016-07-14T15:15:24.835+0000 I STORAGE  [conn1264360] passes = 5000 in CappedRecordStoreV1::allocRecord: ns: local.oplog.rs, lenToAlloc: 3572180, maxCappedDocs: 9223372036854775807, nrecords: 
85033228, datasize: 52320114660. Continuing to delete old records to make room.
2016-07-14T15:29:56.434+0000 I STORAGE  [conn1265954] passes = 5000 in CappedRecordStoreV1::allocRecord: ns: local.oplog.rs, lenToAlloc: 3332760, maxCappedDocs: 9223372036854775807, nrecords: 
85035131, datasize: 52320300492. Continuing to delete old records to make room.
2016-07-14T15:30:01.777+0000 I STORAGE  [conn1265954] passes = 5000 in CappedRecordStoreV1::allocRecord: ns: local.oplog.rs, lenToAlloc: 3572748, maxCappedDocs: 9223372036854775807, nrecords: 
85029980, datasize: 52320290816. Continuing to delete old records to make room.
```

which caused a lot of sync disk IO and at some point Linux OS Ubuntu 14.04 LTS just decided to stop process and wait for IO to finish

```
    [12114362.224095] INFO: task mongod:15282 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[12114362.255630] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
```

which in it's turn caused mongo replicaset election and failover to another node. 
The thing is, after mongodb node got into SECONDARY state, this behaviour continued

```
2016-07-14T16:32:55.894+0000 I STORAGE  [rsSync] passes = 5000 in CappedRecordStoreV1::allocRecord: ns: local.oplog.rs, lenToAlloc: 3334112, maxCappedDocs: 9223372036854775807, nrecords: 85033970, datasize: 52320484040. Continuing to delete old records to make room.
2016-07-14T16:47:11.358+0000 I STORAGE  [rsSync] passes = 5000 in CappedRecordStoreV1::allocRecord: ns: local.oplog.rs, lenToAlloc: 3334116, maxCappedDocs: 9223372036854775807, nrecords: 85029709, datasize: 52320442564. Continuing to delete old records to make room.
2016-07-14T16:47:15.346+0000 I STORAGE  [rsSync] passes = 5000 in CappedRecordStoreV1::allocRecord: ns: local.oplog.rs, lenToAlloc: 3574168, maxCappedDocs: 9223372036854775807, nrecords: 85024240, datasize: 52320158028. Continuing to delete old records to make room.
```

Mongo version 3.0.7, mmap storage engine
I use the following sysctl settings for dirty pages

```
vm.dirty_background_ratio = 5
vm.dirty_background_bytes = 0
vm.dirty_ratio = 25
vm.dirty_bytes = 0
```

Any idea what's happening?

Comment: Note that "STORAGE I " means it's an informational message from the storage engine layer, *not* an error or even a warning.  However, it does seem like you don't have enough disk IO bandwidth for your workload - or possibly your disk isn't optimized (or your schema or workload).  That's a much bigger question than can be explored via SO.

Comment: we run AWS instance with 4 drives on top of SSD in striped lvm. I don't have any visibility into actual hardware, so I can assume that it might be some HW perfomance related issue during this time - but I can't prove/disprove it.